# How to create our own portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

Please describe me in brief how to create portlets using eclipse ide and to add these in liferay.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE) (which comes as a plugin) in Eclipse, can download it from [here](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide).

And then create a Liferay project the same way as you create a normal Eclipse project by going to File --> New --> Liferay Project --> A window will open which will ask you about what kind of project you need to create in liferay (portlet, hooks, theme, ext, layout etc).

Some more links to get you started with Liferay IDE:

- [Installation guide for Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Installation+Guide)
- [Getting started with Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

File->New->Liferay project->
Enter the name[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

click ok
It will show project
and then goto  docroot/WEB-INF/src
create a portlet here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, see the screencast:

[image]